# What is the relationship between $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ if $A \subseteq B$ but $A\neq B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are sets, that $f : X \to Y$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ and that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$. Given a subset $C \subseteq X$ let $f(C) = \{y ∈ Y : y = f(c) \text{ for some } c ∈ C\} \subseteq Y$.

I have proved that if $A \subseteq B$ then $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$. 
Proof: let $y \in f(A)$. Then there exists $a \in A \subseteq B$ such that $f(a) = y$. Since $a \in B \Rightarrow f(a) \in f(b) \Rightarrow f(A) \subseteq f(B)$.

Using this as a guide, I would assume $f(A)$ is can still be $\subseteq$ of $f(B)$ because $A \subseteq B$ can either coincide or not coincide but I'm not too sure.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: The sentence "Since $a ∈ B \Rightarrow f(a) ∈ f(b) \Rightarrow f(A) ⊆ f(B)$." is an abstract nonsense. Who is $b$? I guess you mean that since $a \in B$, then $y = f(a) \in f(B)$ by definition of $f(B)$; therefore $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Without any hypothesis on the function $f \colon X \to Y$, you can only say that, given $A, B \subseteq X$, if $A \subseteq B$ then $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$, as you have already proven.

You can't say that $A \subsetneq B$ implies $f(A) \subsetneq f(B)$ (where $C \subsetneq D$ means that $C$ is a proper subset of $D$, i.e. $C \subseteq D$ and $C \neq D$, for all sets $C$ and $D$); in other words, you can have that $A \subsetneq B$ but $f(A) = f(B)$. This is an example: let $f \colon \{0,1\} \to \{2\}$ be the function defined by $f(0) = 2$ and $f(1) = 2$. Then, $\{0\} \subsetneq \{0,1\}$ but $f(\{0\}) = \{2\} = f(\{0,1\})$.

Anyway, if you suppose that moreover the function $f \colon X \to Y$ is *injective* (i.e. $x_1 \neq x_2$ implies $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$), then you can prove also that $A \subsetneq B$ implies $f(A) \subsetneq f(B)$. *Proof:* We already know that $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$, so we have just to prove that $f(A) \neq f(B)$. Since $A \subsetneq B$, there exists a $b \in B \smallsetminus A$; then $f(b) \in f(B)$ but $f(b) \notin f(A)$, otherwise there would be an $a \in A$ (and hence $a \neq b$ since $b \notin A$) such that $f(a) = f(b)$, which is impossible because $f$ is injective. Therefore, $f(A) \neq f(B)$.